# How To Deal with Large set of data in Nodejs, that need to be classified using python then save the result

Tags: python, mysql, node.js, cron

we have a task that need to be done on 900,000 record daily that in nodejs i seprated this task to be used by  a corn job
steps :

1- fetch the data that is  need to be processed

2- loop throw each record

- Classify the data
- update the current record
- save classification result
- List item

3-run the cron job daily

if the fetched data from step one 500k record
and if each record is got processed in 1s (may be more) so it will take 5 days to be done

what is the most efficient way to do this in nodejs

Comment: 1s is a lot of time, why does it take that long? You might want to profile the code to get some insight.

Comment: after adding logs table to help me in debugging, i found that it processed in average 1500 record per hour 
25 record per min
so its still slow    compared to number of data that is need to be processed

Comment: Again, run the code under a node.js profiler, it will tell you the areas that need improving. After that, if not enough performance gain, you might need to paralelize, add a queue for writing to the db asynchronously, etc.